# Is it possible to integrate raw ruby apps (not rails) with flex?

Tags: ruby, apache-flex

I´m looking for any kind of information on this subject, kinda hard to find. I´m a ruby programmer and i´m looking for ways to create web apps with RIA, like Adobe Flex. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Flex can access any backend using [HTTPService](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Flivedocs.adobe.com%2Fflex%2F3%2Fhtml%2Fdata_access_2.html&rct=j&q=Flex%20HTTPService&ei=FdctTbmnM8jogQfR3KyzDA&usg=AFQjCNGYeCtHD8cekh3QloF5hekzZFoC8Q&cad=rja), which is for REST calls, [WebService](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Flivedocs.adobe.com%2Fflex%2F3%2Fhtml%2Fdata_access_3.html&rct=j&q=Flex%20WebService&ei=JdctTdnWHMjAgQfWoP2zDA&usg=AFQjCNHD0JfX3JGTe2tEZRtoBHgorT_m6Q&cad=rja), for SOAP calls, or [RemoteObject](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/data_access_4.html) for AMF (sometimes called Flash Remoting) calls.  Flex doesn't care what that remote service is built in.

For an AMF solution, [RubyAMF](https://github.com/victorcoder/rubyamf_plugin) came up in Google.

I would assume a Ruby knowledgeable person can easily create a REST and/or SOAP web service.  I am not Ruby Knowledgeable, so can't offer specifics on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get that.
I have no idea about Flash/Flex stuff , but you say RIA which stands for rich internet applications, and you're saying you want to use it with RIA...err huh?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are asking if there is any way to create a client side RIA using Ruby as you are a Ruby developer.

If you want to create a Flex application you will need to learn ActionScript and the Flex API.

However, if you are just looking for a RIA solution that will allow you to develop in Ruby, I believe Microsoft Silverlight now supports Ruby and Python.  I'm completely unfamiliar with Silverlight, but these articles should hopefully get you going in the right direction:

http://www.devx.com/RIA/Article/40465
http://www.silverlight.net/learn/dynamic-languages/